# Shader texture values not the same as written when creating the texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I have created a texture and filled it with ones:

```
size_t size = width * height * 4;
float *pixels = new float[size];
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    pixels[i] = 1.0f;
}

glTextureStorage2D(texture_id, 1, GL_RGBA16F, width,
                   height);
glTextureSubImage2D(texture_id, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA,
                    GL_FLOAT, pixels);
```

I use linear filtering (`GL_LINEAR`) and clamp to border.

But when I draw the image:

```
color = texture(atlas, uv);
```

the last row looks like it has alpha values of less than 1. If in the shader I set the alpha to 1:

```
color.a = 1.0f;
```

it draws it correctly. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the combination of `GL_LINEAR` and `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER`:

- Clamp to border means that every texture coordinate outside of [0, 1]
  will return the border color. This color can be set with
  `glTexParameterf(..., GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, ...)` and is black by
  default.
- Linear filter will take into account pixels that are adjacent to the
  sampling location (unless sampling happens exactly at texel centers<sup>1</sup>),
  and will thus also read border color texels (which are here black).

If you don't want this behavior, the simplest solution would be to use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` instead which will repeat the last row/column of texels to infinity. The different wrapping modes are explained very well explained at [open.gl](https://open.gl/textures).

<sub>1) Sampling happens most probably not at pixel centers [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916938/incorrect-result-when-using-3d-textures/26917191#26917191).</sub>